# I want to have a jQuery mouse scroll animation effect similar to the site https://onlycoin.com/

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, parallax, mousewheel

As mentioned in the title, https://onlycoin.com/ has a smooth mouse scroll effect of the cards getting animated when we scroll.

I want to achieve something similar to that. I have made the webpage. Instead of the cards, I have mobile phones that will animate in that  .

Can anyone help me on how I should proceed to do it ?

I have already done the HTML coding on the page and I am really confused with the jquery.animate(); function.

Therefore, the only reference site i know is the one I posted above.

I am a novice in jquery.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to provide you with a complete explanation, but I put this together to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7gw/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box" id="right"></div>
<div class="box" id="center"></div>
<div class="box" id="left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {height: 1000px; width: 1000px; background-color: #000;}
.box {width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -50px; margin-top: -50px; background-color: #ff0000;}
#right {background-color: #aa0000;}
#left {background-color: #aa0000;}
```

JS

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var leftBox = $('#left').position();
var rightBox = $('#right').position();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#right').css({left: rightBox.left + st});
    $('#left').css({left: leftBox.left - st});
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the idea I was looking for.Now, I can customise it according to the design and effects I have in mind.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer with the checkmark to the left if it was considered a solution to your problem :)